# Chart JS - Click not triggering until after mouse move

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm struggling to understand why when you click on the chart the number in the middle does not get updated until the user moves their cursor after the chart has been clicked upon.

```
  onClick: function(event, chart) {
    var index = chart[0]._index;
    var value = ~~percentages[index];
    chart[0]._chart.config.options.elements.center.text = value;
  },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uL8L5ny9/

I've created a JS fiddle where you can see this happening.

From my experience this is a problem in Chrome and FF so far.

I am actually using NG2 charts on my project but the JS fiddle using just chart.js is doing the same thing.

I haven't found much on the internet about this issue.

Comment: Updated - This happens when you hover off of the chart.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to draw/update the chart on load. Using the chart.chart.update() fixes this.